# Codigo de respuesta http para un error al guardar un fichero

Tags: javascript, html, http, http-post

Tengo una gran duda, estoy recibiendo ficheros en mi servidor con Multer, si por alguna razón fallara, y que fuera una falla controlada, es decir que supongamos que falle porque está recibiendo más ficheros de los permitidos, cual es el código http con el que debo responder?
Estoy entre responder con el código 200 y envíar un JSON indicando que hay un error ó responder con algún código 5XX.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: En mi opinión es mejor responder con un 5XX, el otro caso el front tendria que verificar el código del error y verificar si le llego algún error, en el primer caso solo tiene que ver cual es el código

Answer (score 1):

Segun las mejroes practicas al Implementar Rest API o cualquier otra variantes estas serian los reponses recomendados:

Respuestas básicas ([LINK](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-error-handling-best-practices#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20some%20common%20response,to%20access%20the%20requested%20resource))
La forma más sencilla de manejar los errores es responder con un código de estado apropiado.

Estos son algunos códigos de respuesta comunes:

- 400 Solicitud incorrecta: el cliente envió una solicitud no válida, como falta de cuerpo o parámetro de solicitud requerido
- 401 No autorizado: el cliente no pudo autenticarse con el servidor
- 403 Prohibido: cliente autenticado pero no tiene permiso para acceder al recurso solicitado
- 404 No encontrado: el recurso solicitado no existe
- 412 Precondición fallida: una o más condiciones en los campos del encabezado de la solicitud se evaluaron como falsas
- 500 Error interno del servidor: se produjo un error genérico en el servidor
- 503 Servicio no disponible: el servicio solicitado no está disponible

Entonces dependiendo de el error controlado deberias desecadenar el codigo adecuado ... lo cual depende de tu desarrollo... obviamente hay otros codigos de respuesta ...